# Issue with SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm having an issue with my SQL in marketing cloud to fusion 2 data extensions :

```
Select 
contacts.Contact_ID 
contacts.Societe_ID 
contacts.Mail 
demandes.Demande_id 
demandes.Societe_id 
demandes.Type_immo 
demandes.Stade 
demandes.Surf_max 
FROM 
CONTACTS 
INNER JOIN COMPANIES
On contacts.Societe_id = companies.Societe_id 
INNER JOIN DEMANDES
On COMPANIES.Societe_id = DEMANDES.Societe_id
```

Can someone help me to solve this ?

Thank you in advance :)

Anna

Comment: Hi Anna, You may be on the wrong forum here: how does this relate to Salesforce?

Comment: Hello Keith, This is an SQL in Marketing cloud

Comment: do you have CONTACTS AND COMPANIES DEMANDES  Data extensions is there in your mc account ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the issue is? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

If your account contains above DEs means try like this query

```
  Select 
 c.Contact_ID,
 c.Societe_ID, 
 c.Mail,
 d.Demande_id, 
  d.Societe_id, 
 d.Type_immo, 
 d.Stade, 
 d.Surf_max 
 FROM 
 CONTACTS as c
 INNER JOIN COMPANIES as co
 On c.Societe_id = co.Societe_id 
INNER JOIN DEMANDES as d
 On co.Societe_id = d.Societe_id
```

Comment: what was that issue ? post here

Comment: It is Working :) :) :) 
Thank you PKharries

Comment: @Anna--> i hope this query help you Make my answer is best

Comment: 0


New error for me : I modify it a little bit the SQL:

Select Contact_ID as 'c.Contact_ID', ID_Societe as 'c.Societe_ID', Mail as 'c.Mail', Demande_ID as 'd.Demande_id', Type_Immo as 'd.Type_immo', Stade as 'd.Stade', Surf_Max as 'd.Surf_max' FROM CONTACTS as c INNER JOIN COMPANIES as com On c.Societe_id = com.Societe_id INNER JOIN DEMANDES as d On com.Societe_id = d.Societe_id

I'm not sure i'm going in the right way for this SQL. I need to mutualize those 7 fields in one DE to filter and send an email.

Comment: i think fields is  different  your DEs but your not post here